# <div> under <ol>, works in browser, but is it legit?

Tags: html

Please consider the following HTML code:

```
<ol>
    <li>aaaa</li>
    <div style="background-color : red">
        <li>aaaa</li>
        <li>aaaa</li>
        <li>aaaa</li>
    </div>
    <li>aaaa</li>
</ol>
```

Is this legit? 
Although the specs says no, [link](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/grouping-content.html#the-ol-element), but the code seems to behave perfect under Chrome and Safari. What would be the downside of using such HTML code?

UPDATE: thanks for all the answers. Is there a different valid solution to group a few list items with some "logical container"?

Comment: FYI, the [W3C Validator](https://validator.w3.org) complains that "document type does not allow element "div" here; assuming missing "li" start-tag".

Comment: @Ken Y-N: Good to know that the validator is working according to the spec then?

Comment: "Is there a different valid solution to group a few list items with some 'logical container'?" Not really, sadly, HTML doesn't support doing this without breaking up the list entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, It will work just fine and should work in all major browsers, the downside is that it isn't valid. It's not necessarily hurting anything, but since we live in a testable, verifiable world, it's technically counter spec, so it's not to standard.

Answer (score 3):

It's not legit, but browsers are extremely forgiving and will still try to render something as best as they can, even if the HTML you give it is technically wrong.

Answer (score 1):

What makes is not compliant is that it goes against the reasoning of having particular html [symantics](https://www.thoughtco.com/why-use-semantic-html-3468271).

The list helps screen readers and crawlers understand the content better. This can help with the users experience as well as assist with proper content indexing and archiving by search engines.

Answer (score 1):

What I do if I'm ever unsure if something is valid or not; I go to [W3C validator](https://validator.w3.org/) and input the html. As long as you input a full html file it will tell you if it's valid or not. :)

The website gives you three options for validating html:

1. Validate by URI (Just enter the webpage that you want to validate.
2. Validate by File Upload (upload the html file that you would like to validate.
3. Validate by Direct Input (Copy and paste or type the html code)

I usually do option 3 because I use PHP a lot, so I load the webpage then get the html after the scripting (right click -> view page source) then copy and paste that into the input box.

Comment: The asker knows it's invalid - they cited the spec as saying no. They're asking if it's acceptable to use invalid markup that's known to be interoperable.

Answer (score 1):

**Is this legit?** No.

Although browser show perfectly but W3C Validator will not permit you write this way. You will get error if you go with your code in validation engine. Validator will show you message like following.

> **Error:** Element div not allowed as child of element ol in this context.

Also see the ["Semantics, structure, and APIs of HTML documents" section of the WHATWG HTML specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#dom) to get overall idea.